# Why doesn't the JVM crash when entering infinite recursion?

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm writing a shared library to be loaded into the JVM and the behavior below got me stuck. Here are my Java classes:

```
package com.test;

public class UnixUtil {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("myfancylibrary");
    }
    static native int openReadOnlyFd(String path);
    static native int closeFd(int fd);
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int fd = UnixUtil.openReadOnlyFd("/tmp/testc");
        UnixUtil.closeFd(fd);
    }
}
```

And the library to be loaded looks like:

test_jni.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_test_UnixUtil */

#ifndef _Included_com_test_UnixUtil
#define _Included_com_test_UnixUtil
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_test_UnixUtil
 * Method:    openReadOnlyFd
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_UnixUtil_openReadOnlyFd
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     com_test_UnixUtil
 * Method:    closeFd
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

test_jni.c

```
#include "test_jni.h"
#include "fs.h"


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_UnixUtil_openReadOnlyFd
  (JNIEnv *e, jclass jc, jstring path){
  const char *const native_path = ((*e) -> GetStringUTFChars)(e, path, NULL);
  int fd = read_only_open(native_path);
  ((*e) -> ReleaseStringUTFChars)(e, path, native_path);
  return fd;
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd
   (JNIEnv *e, jclass jc, jint fd){
   printf("Closing files descriptord %d... \n", fd);
   return close(fd);
}
```

fs.h

```
#ifndef FS_H
#define FS_H

int read_only_open(const char *path);

int close(int fd);

#endif //FS_H
```

fs.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

#include "fs.h"

int read_only_open(const char *path){
    printf("Entering %s.%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    return fd;
}

int close(int fd){ //Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd does not invoke this function
    printf("Entering %s.%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
    int close_result = close(fd);
    return close_result;
}
```

When compiling and running this `Main` class the JVM ***does not crash***. It simply does not enter the function `fs.h::close(int)`. Instead, `stdlib`'s `close`  is called as can be seen in GDB:

```
Thread 2 "java" hit Breakpoint 1, Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd (e=<optimized out>,
    jc=<optimized out>, fd=4) at /home/rjlomov/test_jni/src/main/java/com/test/lib/test_jni.c:17
17        return close(fd);
(gdb) step
18      }
(gdb) 
17        return close(fd);
(gdb) 
__close (fd=4) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/close.c:27
27      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/close.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
26      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/close.c
```

Running `objdump -dS libmyfancylibrary.so` shows that

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd                                                                                                                                                              
  (JNIEnv *e, jclass jc, jint fd){                                                                                                                                                                                 
 7d0:   53                      push   %rbx                                                                                                                                                                        
}   

//...

  return close(fd);                                                                                                                                                                                                
 7e9:   e9 62 fe ff ff          jmpq   650 <close@plt>   // <--- PLT section,
                                      // resolved by linker to stdlib::close?                                                                                                                                                         
 7ee:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

***QUESTION:*** Why is `stdlib::close` called in `Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd` instead of `fs.c::close(int)`? The only thing I can imagine is the JVM has its own dynamic linker which does the job...

Comment: try to change the name from this very specific one.

Comment: @P__J__ Yes, it will work. But I'm just curious of how it works, because similar code worked for pretty long time until my colleague suddenly caught it. Can dynamic linker simply throw away functions that it is already know about?

Comment: Some functions probably are built in and have special meaning which cannot be changed by user code.

Comment: @P__J__ Actually I also tried to build a simple hand-written binary to check if the behavior would be the same and linked it with a similar shared library (replacing `test_jni.c`'s functions needed by JVM with `int do_open_fd(const char *path);` and `void do_close_fd(int fd);`)  and it crashed with SEGV as expected...

Comment: @Holger _You didn’t include the contents of test_jni.h_ I intentionally omitted it because it was generated by `javac -h . com/test/UnixUtil.java` and then renamed to `test_jni.h`. `#define close(X) implementation_specific_name(X)` but would that mean that `fs.c::close(int)` would also preprocessed this way introducing 2 definitions of `implementation_specific_name`.

Comment: @Holger Anyway I just checked the preprocessed `test_jni.c file` and the only difference in `jint Java_com_test_UnixUtil_closeFd` was that it had `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` prepended to it. The `return close(fd);` is left unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are compiling a shared library, and the function `close()` is not `static`, the compiler makes an indirect call throught the Procedure Linkage Table (PLT). When disassembling the library you'll likely see an instruction

```
    call <close@plt>
```

When `myfancylibrary` is loaded, the process already has the implementation of `close` from libc, so the dynamic liker updates PLT to point to libc's version of `close()`.